# Need help in implementing q-SeriesToq-Product in Mathematica

Tags: programming, symbolic

In Mathematica Guidebook for symbolic computations ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387950206/wolframresearch-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387950206)), in the Exercises, 30 (c)(p. 359), there is a question:
[image: qseriestoqproduct]

I have no clue how to implement this or how to proceed with this!. Help me how to deal with this?
So far what i know: There is a built in command for converting product to series:

```
Series[Product[(1 - x^n), {n, 1, Infinity}], {x, 0, 100}]
```

But the problem at my hand is exactly the reverse one!. Any suggestions greatly appreciated. Found the the following theorem, which guides conversion. Need to implementation of the following theorem in Mathematica:
[image]

Comment: If this is homework, then you should add the appropriate tag. In any case, you should show some work of your own. For instance, at least you could try to reproduce the Series object using `Series`.

Comment: Start by converting the product into a series.

Comment: There is a built in command for converting product to series: Series[Product[(1 - x^n), {n, 1, Infinity}], {x, 0, 100}]. But now, I have been given with series, 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nq^n, the requirement is that i need to convert this series into product \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-q^k)^\alpha_k. This problem is exact reverse one.

Comment: @Sangama It was a hint how to *start*. You then have to figure out what $\alpha_k$ will make the two series equal. You’re not going to find a command that directly turns a series into a product. You *have* to approach the problem in the “exact reverse” way.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we need to do this for a specific value of $n$, not in all generality:

```
n = 3;
Σ = 1 + Sum[c[k] q^k, {k, n}];
Π = Product[(1 - q^k)^α[k], {k, n}];
```

Use an explicit variant of [`SolveAlways`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveAlways.html) to be able to specify which variables we need to find:

```
ΠΠ = Π /. FullSimplify[First[
  Solve[!Eliminate[Normal[Series[Π - Σ, {q, 0, n}]] != 0, q],
        Array[α, n]]]]

(*    (1 - q)^-c[1] *
      (1 - q^2)^(1/2 (c[1] + c[1]^2 - 2 c[2])) *
      (1 - q^3)^(1/3 (c[1] - c[1]^3 + 3 c[1] c[2] - 3 c[3]))    *)

Series[ΠΠ - Σ, {q, 0, n}] // FullSimplify
(*    O[q]^4    *)
```

As a one-liner,

```
qSeriesToqProduct[cc_] := With[{n = Length[cc]},
  First[SolveValues[
    !Eliminate[Normal[Series[
      1 + cc . q^Range[n] - Product[(1 - q^k)^α[k], {k, n}],
      {q, 0, n}]] != 0, q], Array[α, n]]]]

qSeriesToqProduct[{c1, c2, c3, c4}]
(*    {-c1,
       1/2 (c1 + c1^2 - 2 c2),
       1/3 (c1 - c1^3 + 3 c1 c2 - 3 c3), 
       1/4 (-c1^2 + c1^4 + 2 c2 - 4 c1^2 c2 + 2 c2^2 + 4 c1 c3 - 4 c4)}    *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much